# Hadoop dfs put fails

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I am getting this error (hadoop dfs -put) when the process is triggered from a shell script (run by Jenkins) during the nigh, however, it runs OK if I try manually later.

```
put: Lease mismatch on /shared/file1.tsv._COPYING_ owned by DFSClient_NONMAPREDUCE_-2031300157_1 but is accessed by DFSClient_NONMAPREDUCE_-1375175076_1

13/08/07 07:11:39 ERROR hdfs.DFSClient: Failed to close file /shared/epg/programs/programs/20130812/programs__20130812_20130807.tsv._COPYING_
```

any suggestion why this might happen?